# Release memory between foreach iterations in release builds?

Tags: c#, foreach, garbage-collection

**UPDATE**
Obviously, the original question was confusing so I'll try to simplify it.

I'm working with a complex algorithme that is providing a list of object (let's say a company).
For each of those company I will have to load a large amount of data (let's say a list of employee).

```
public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public List<Employee> EmployeeList { get; set; } = new List<Employee>();
}

public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = "Random first name";
    public string LastName { get; set; } = "Random last name";
}

public MemoryTest()
{
    //Simulate the complex algorithme... 
    //I can't change how I get that list and my question ain't about this part.
    List<Company> companyList = new List<Company>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
    {
        companyList.Add(new Company() {  Name = "Random company name " + i });
    }

    //Simulate the details loading.  This is where the memory gets filled            
    foreach (Company company in companyList)
    {
        company.EmployeeList.AddRange(new Employee[25000]);
        //Do some calculation and save to DB...
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that the memory allocated during each iteration won't be released until the end of the loop.

After reading [this article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/.net-framework/understanding-garbage-collection-in-.net/) I had hopes that the JIT would be able to determine a company reference would not be used after an iteration since the companyList isn't use beyond the foreach:

> In release builds, the JIT is able to look at the program structure to work out the last point
> within the execution that a variable can be used by the method and will discard it when it is
> no longer required.

... but sadly, the JIT doesn't extrapolate that far.

In order to use a few memory as possible, my question is the following:  Is there a way the loop thru a collection AND to remove reference to the element between each iteration?

**Here's a more generic example if you don't want to work with Company / Employee**

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    dict.Add(i, new List<string>());
}

foreach (var item in dict)
{
    item.Value.AddRange(new string[25000]);
}
```

Comment: The GC doesn't remove things from memory as soon as they're no longer needed. It spins in its own thread, removing things from memory that it finds are no longer needed. My gut says you come from an unmanaged programming background. Just let go of memory management in C#. You only need to worry about it in very rare situations. Just let it do its thing.

Comment: Don’t try to guess what will actually happen in a runtime of a production build. The list might be eligible to garbage collection even before the loop ends, as a consequence of loop unrolling, for example. Further reading https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=13193

Comment: you should not have the objects rooted to the collection to begin with.  use an iterator method to create them instead.

Comment: It sounds like you have other ownership issues with the collection then. Even removing them from the collection doesn't get around the initial allocation of the entire collection.  You have to create them all in memory to start with.  So you must be creating multiple collections and holding onto those collections

Comment: @MikeJ the initial allocation itself doesn't take much memory.  Most of the memory is allocated during the loop by loading company details.

Comment: ok, I think I see, I'll update my answer.  The issue then is the relationship you have between the item and the expensive data .  You should invert that relationship and not attach the data to the dictionary bound item. To put that another way, the item in the dictionary is a key for the company data?  you should yield out the completed company item and not add it to something in the dictionary

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to revise me original answer here.  Not to beat the proverbial dead horse but I just want to emphasize that if you're having to pop items out of a collection to keep the collection from rooting the objects in memory then it's almost certain you've got some issues with the design of the your application.  There might be some scenarios where that's a great design but I say most often it's not.

Lets take Smurf's company scenario and change it slightly to make it not hold onto large objects in the collection at all.

I'm going to ignore the dictionary of Company objects.  It's never used as a dictionary and is only used as a collection.  It's also important to note that what's in the dictionary to begin with is not a complete company object.  We had to use the original company object to retrieve the extra data.  We usually call that a key.  So instead of that dictionary, we'll have a stream of keys instead.  Here's the key objects:

```
public class CompanyKey
{ }
```

And a data source to produce keys.  This might actually be Smurfs dictionary, but for our purposes we'll make it an iterator method.  That way nothing is rooting these things in memory. If the keys are small then it doesn't really matter but better to not use a collection if you don't need it.

```
public class CompanyKeySource
{
    public IEnumerable<CompanyKey> GetKeys()
    {
        for(int i =0;i < 10;++i)
            yield return new CompanyKey();
    }
}
```

And here's the actual company object:

```
public class Company
{
    public EmployeeData Employees { get; set; }
}
```

And the big glob of data.  That's in the employee object.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string[] LotOfData { get; set; }
}
```

Finally we need something that'll load the big glob of data into the company object.  That's usually a repository of some type:

```
public class CompanyDataRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Company> GetCompanyDetails(IEnumerable<CompanyKey> keys)
    {
        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            yield return new Company() { Employees = GetEmployees(key) };
        }
    }

    public EmployeeData GetEmployees(CompanyKey key) =>
        new EmployeeData() { LotOfData = new string[2500] };
}
```

Now we wire everything together and iterate over our company instances.

```
    static void Main(string[] _)
    {
        CompanyDataRepository repository = new CompanyDataRepository();
        CompanyKeySource keySource = new CompanyKeySource();

        var keys = keySource.GetKeys();

        foreach (var company in repository.GetCompanyDetails(keys))
        {
            // do whatever it is you're doing with your companies...
        }
    }
```

Now there's no need to pop items off a dictionary to keep them out of memory.  The large chunks of data are used where they're needed and then can be eligible for collection right away.

Comment: Very interesting!  How would you translate the your example to the dictionary example?

Comment: I don't understand your dictionary example.  You're allocating a large block of memory and then removing the item that holds that memory.  What's the point?  What does the original item matter in this case?  (this is from your answer not the question)

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf so instead of removing the items from the dictionary, just yield out the completed items for processing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [MikeJ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64429086/315493), I created a generic method that will loop thru a list and remove the reference to the element right after the iteration:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> PopEnumerable<T>(this List<T> list)
{
    while (list.Count > 0)
    {
        yield return list[0];
        list.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

That way you can still call the foreach loop...

```
foreach (Company company in companyList.PopEnumerable())
{
    company.EmployeeList.AddRange(new Employee[25000]);
}
```

... but only the company of the current iteration will remain in memory.  I did some benchmark and the memory allocation that use to reach 16 gb dropped to less than 100 mb for the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` is using an enumerator concept. With the help of `.MoveNext()` method, it is observing items in the collection one after another with the help of `.Current` property. In other words, your code is translated to something like:

```cs
List<Compagny>.Enumerator enumerator = new List<Compagny>().GetEnumerator();
try
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        Compagny current = enumerator.Current;
        LoadContacts(current);
        current.Log = "Very large string...";
    }
}
finally
{
    ((IDisposable)enumerator).Dispose();
}
```

As you see, each `var compagny` is in the end just a single local variable of reference type. This reference is being replaced in every iteration. So, from this point of view, `current` variable becomes an additional root for some `Compagny` object, for the time of the iteration.

The difference here may be what's the range of such a root. In case of the *Debug* build, it is indeed the whole `{}` block of a underlying `while` loop (in fact, the whole method, from the CIL perspective). In case of *Release* build, JIT is reporting roots more aggresively. So, it will report `current` as no longer needed, as fast as it is indeed no longer needed. In you case, you are using `current` till the end of the `{}` so it is the same.

The difference could be seen if you don't use `compagny` till the end of the block, like:

```cs
foreach (var compagny in compagnyList)
{
    this.LoadContacts(compagny);  
    this.LoadNotes(compagny.ContactList) 
    compagny.Log = "Very large string...";
    CallingHereLongLastingMethod(); // Debug - compagny is still a root
                                    // Release - compagny is no longer a root
}
```

BUT... all this **does not matter** because `current` is just an additional object root. Object itself ("compagny") is still rooted by the `compagnyList` itself.

*"would the GC be smart enough to understand that the company object would not be reused beyond the foreach iteration and mark it as candidate for garbage collection (despite the compagnyList that would remain be on the stack)?"* question suggests you have some problems in understanding reference types and the GC fundamentals. `List<>` is a reference type, it contains of the reference (living "on the stack" as a local variable) and the data - collection of the companies.